# Implementing alpha beta pruning in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm developing the game Teeko in Prolog and I try to implement alpha beta pruning but I do not know where to start. Could someone please guide me? I have already found the minimax algorithm.

Comment: Try a Google search on "prolog alpha beta pruning" to get some ideas. There are a few what appear to be useful links.

Answer (score 5):

> I try to implement alpha beta pruning but I do not know where to start.
>
> Could someone please guide me?
>
> I have already found the minimax algorithm.

### **The short look into alpha beta pruning algorithm**

**Choosing a move using minimax with alpha-beta pruning**

The new relation scheme is `alpha_beta( Depth, Position, Alpha, Beta, Move, Value )`,

which extends minimax by replacing the minimax flag with alpha and beta. The same relation holds with respect to `evaluate_and_choose`.

The program can be generalized by replacing the base case of `alpha_beta` by a test of whether the position is terminal. This is necessary in chess programs, for example, for handling incomplete piece exchanges.

---

`evaluate_and_choose ( Moves, Position, Depth, Alpha, Beta, Record, BestMove )`

- Chooses the **BestMove** from the set of **Moves** from the current
- **Position** using the minimax algorithm with alpha-beta cutoff searching
- **Depth** ply ahead.
- **Alpha** and **Beta** are the parameters of the algorithm.
- **Record** records the current best move.

---

```
evaluate_and_choose([ Move | Moves ], Position, D, Alpha, Beta, Move1, BestMove ) :-
    move( Move, Position, Positionl ),
    alpha_beta( D, Positionl, Alpha, Beta, MoveX, Value ),
    Value1 is -Value,
    cutoff( Move, Value1, D, Alpha, Beta, Moves, Position, Move1, BestMove ).

evaluate_and_choose( [], Position, D, Alpha, Beta, Move, ( Move, Alpha )).

alpha_beta( 0, Position, Alpha, Beta, Move, Value ) :- 
    value( Position, Value ).
    
alpha_beta( D, Position, Alpha, Beta, Move, Value ) :- 
    findall( M, move( Position, M ), Moves ),
    Alphal is -Beta,
    Betal is -Alpha,
    D1 is D-l,
    evaluate_and_choose( Moves, Position, D1, Alphal, Betal, nil, ( Move, Value )).

    
cutoff( Move, Value, D, Alpha, Beta, Moves, Position, Movel, ( Move,Value )) :- 
    Value > Beta.
cutoff(Move, Value, D, Alpha, Beta, Moves, Position, Movel, BestMove ) :- 
    Alpha < Value, Value < Beta,
    evaluate_and_choose( Moves, Position, D, Value, Beta, Move, BestMove ).

cutoff( Move, Value, D, Alpha, Beta, Moves, Position, Movel, BestMove ) :- 
    Value < Alpha,
    evaluate_and_choose( Moves, Position, D, Alpha, Beta, Move1, BestMove ).
```

Comment: what's difficult . more detailed please

Comment: All those arguments are difficult to relate to board state. Just my experience...

Comment: well, most likely you're right. But I've just supplied the example codes. it's start point to go further.

Comment: Of course, you're right. Did you noticed the syntax error (undue rule head) `cutoff( Move, Value, D, Alpha, Beta, Moves, Position, Movel, BestMove ) :- `  ?